# Determine all two times differentiable equations $f$ which satisfy the equation $\int^x_0 (\int^{t^2}_0f(\sqrt{s})^2ds)dt=f(x)+x$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Determine all two times differentiable equations $f$ which satisfy the equation $$\int^x_0 (\int^{t^2}_0f'(\sqrt{s})^2ds)dt=f(x)+x$$

What I've done the following to try to solve it. Differentiating both sides two times gives $f'(\sqrt{x})^2 2x=f''(x)$. So $f'(x)^22x=f''(x)$ has the solution $f'(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2+C}$ and inserted in the equation above it gives $\frac{2x}{(x+C)^2}=f''(x)$. Integrating once gives $\ln((x+C)^2)-2C\sqrt{C}\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{C}}$. Which I need to integrate again but since this is from calc 2 this method is wrong. So I'm wondering why it is wrong to first replace $f(\sqrt{x})$ with $f(x)$ and then solve and insert it in the original equation. Also I would like a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

First $f(0)=0$. Differentiating both sides gives
$$\int^{x^2}_0f'(\sqrt{s})^2ds=f'(x)+1.$$
Letting $x=0$, you can obtain $f'(0)=-1$. Using it in
$$ f'(x)=-\frac1{x^2+C} \tag{*}$$
you have $C=1$. From (*), you have
$$ f(x)=f(x)-f(0)=\int_0^xf'(t)dt=-\int_0^x\frac1{t^2+1}dt=-\arctan(x). $$

Comment: I don't understand the last step. Also $f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2+C}$ is obtained from replacing $f(\sqrt{x})$ with $f(x)$. I'm thinking by replacing a larger set of functions that work and then one should use the equation to get the right ones from the set.

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly where you went wrong, but the solution looks a little different:

---

You know (assuming $x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$):
$$
\begin{align*}
f'\left( x \right) &= -\frac{1}{c_{1} + x^{2}}\\
f\left( x \right) &= \int -\frac{1}{c_{1} + x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x + c_{2}\\
f\left( x \right) &= -\int \frac{1}{c_{1} + x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}x + c_{2}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Substitude $\sqrt{c_{1}} \cdot u := x \implies \operatorname{d}x = \sqrt{c_{1}}\, \operatorname{d}u$ (assuming $c_{1} \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$):
$$
\begin{align*}
f\left( x \right) &= -\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{c_{1}} \cdot \left( 1 + u^{2} \right)}\, \operatorname{d}u + c_{2}\\
f\left( x \right) &= -\frac{1}{c_{1}} \cdot \int \frac{1}{1 + u^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}u + c_{2}\\
f\left( x \right) &= -\frac{1}{c_{1}} \cdot \arctan\left( u \right) + c_{2}\\
f\left( x \right) &= -\frac{1}{c_{1}} \cdot \arctan\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{c_{1}}} \cdot x \right) + c_{2}\\
\end{align*}
$$

(but this is not true for all $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$)

---

Let's check it and find $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ while doing it:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x}\left[ \int_{0}^{t^{2}}\left[ f'\left( \sqrt{s} \right)^{2} \right]\, \operatorname{d}s \right]\, \operatorname{d}t &= f\left( x \right) + x\\
\end{align*}
$$

We know $f\left( x \right) = -\frac{1}{c_{1}} \cdot \arctan\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{c_{1}}} \cdot x \right) + c_{2}$ and $f'\left( x \right) = -\frac{1}{c_{1} + x^{2}}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x}\left[ \int_{0}^{t^{2}}\left[ \left( -\frac{1}{c_{1} + \left( \sqrt{s} \right)^{2}} \right)^{2} \right]\, \operatorname{d}s \right]\, \operatorname{d}t &= f\left( x \right) + x\\
\int_{0}^{x}\left[ \int_{0}^{t^{2}}\left[ \frac{1}{\left( c_{1} + s \right)^{2}} \right]\, \operatorname{d}s \right]\, \operatorname{d}t &= f\left( x \right) + x\\
\end{align*}
$$

We know $\int \left( x + c \right)^{n}\, \operatorname{d}x = \frac{1}{n + 1} \cdot \left( x + c \right)^{n + 1} + \text{constant}$ (where $n \ne -1$ or $n = -2$ in our example):
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x}\left[ -\frac{1}{c_{1} + s} \mid_{0}^{t^{2}} \right]\, \operatorname{d}t &= f\left( x \right) + x\\
\int_{0}^{x}\left[ -\frac{1}{c_{1} + t^{2}} - \left( -\frac{1}{c_{1}} \right) \right]\, \operatorname{d}t &= f\left( x \right) + x\\
\underbrace{-\int_{0}^{x}\left[ \frac{1}{c_{1} + t^{2}} \right]\, \operatorname{d}x}_{= f\left( t \right) \mid_{0}^{x}} + \int_{0}^{x} \left[ \frac{1}{c_{1}} \right]\, \operatorname{d}t &= f\left( x \right) + x\\
\end{align*}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
f\left( t \right)\mid_{0}^{x} + \frac{1}{c_{1}} \cdot t \mid_{0}^{x} &= f\left( x \right) + x\\
f\left( x \right) - f\left( 0 \right) + \frac{1}{c_{1}} \cdot \left( x - 0 \right) &= f\left( x \right) + x\\
-\frac{1}{c_{1}} \cdot \arctan\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{c_{1}}} \cdot x \right) + \frac{1}{c_{1}} \cdot x &= -\frac{1}{c_{1}} \cdot \arctan\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{c_{1}}} \cdot x \right) + c_{2} + x\\
\end{align*}
$$

This is only true for $c_{1} = 1 \wedge c_{2} = 0$. So:
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
f\left( x \right) &= -\arctan\left( x \right)\\
\end{align*}
$}$$